# Induced Groups of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am working on a problem from Basic Algebra II and am having some trouble understanding how to proceed. The question is as follows:

> Let G be a group of linear transformations in a finite dimensional vector space V over an algebraically closed field F such that there exists an integer $m$ not divisible by the characteristic of F such that $a^m$ = 1 for all a $\in$ G. Prove that G is finite.

The question suggests to proceed by induction on dimensionality while considering invariant subspaces. Supposing $U$ is a subspace stabilized by $G$, we are asked to look at induced groups of transformations on $U$ and $V/U$. What are these induced groups? I feel I am missing something very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ stabilizes $U$, then each element $g\in G$ restricts to a linear transformation $g|_U:U\to U$.  The set of all these restrictions $g|_U$ is a group $G'$ of linear transformations of $U$, and so you can try to apply the induction hypothesis to $G'$.

Similarly, each element $g\in G$ induces a map $V/U\to V/U$ defined by $g(v+U)=g(v)+U$ (this is well-defined since $g$ maps $U$ to itself).  These maps $V/U\to V/U$ form a group $G''$ of linear transformations of $V/U$ to which you can try to apply the induction hypothesis.

Finally, to prove that $G$ is finite, you'll want to prove that if both $G'$ and $G''$ are finite, $G$ must have been finite.  In this step you will need to use the assumption that $m$ is not divisible by the characteristic of $F$.

Comment: Should I attempt this by induction on the dimension of each of these separately?

Comment: No, you are only proving one statement by induction.  Namely, you are proving the problem statement holds, by (strong) induction on $\dim V$.  Notice that if $U$ is nontrivial (not $0$ or $V$), then $\dim U$ and $\dim V/U$ will both be less than $\dim V$.  So if you can show that the hypotheses of the problem statement are true of $G'$ and $G''$, by the induction hypothesis you can conclude that $G'$ and $G''$ are finite.

Comment: I am confused on how one would go about showing this. There are many examples I keep finding of groups of finite exponent which are infinite. I don't know how to approach this problem.